# Map entity with @SecondaryTable Annotation Spring Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

In my db I have two tables which look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Lokal` (
  `idLokal` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Ocena_idOcena` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idLokal`,`Ocena_idOcena`),
  KEY `fk_Lokal_Ocena_idx` (`Ocena_idOcena`)
)


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ocena` (
  `idOcena` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Ocena` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idOcena`)
)
```

I want to map my `Lokal` entity to this `Ocena` table using `@SecondaryTable` `Hibernate` annotation, what I managed to achieve is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Lokal")
@SecondaryTable(name = "Ocena", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="Ocena_idOcena"))
public class Lokal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idLokal")
    private int id; 
    @Column(table="Ocena" ,name="idOcena")
    private int rating;

    //--Getters and Setters skipped--//

}
```

But all I get is an error saying:

```
ERROR: Unknown column 'this_1_.Ocena_idOcena' in 'on clause'
```

I think I'm misunderstanding the `@SecondaryTable` annotation, but this is my first Spring/Hibernate application so I'd be glad for any kind of help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Lokal")
@SecondaryTable(name = "Ocena", pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="idOcena"))
public class Lokal {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="idLokal")
    private int id; 
    @Column(table="Ocena" ,name="rating")
    private int rating;

    //--Getters and Setters skipped--//

}
```

Comment: I did try this option as well, this throws me another error:
`Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.crud.spring.entity.Lokal column: idOcena (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Comment: thats because `rating` has the same column name as your primary key.

Comment: I changed column's name to Ocena (rating isnt working since I dont have such column in Ocena's table) no more errors, but now I'm not reciving any results from DB, If I remove `@SecondaryTable` annotation it is working properly tho(but not showing columns from Ocena table).

Comment: I found out, that I'm not getting any data from Ocena's table(nulls), even that it is mapped correctly, every Lokal's object should have its own rating, but in my View Rating Cloumn is empty.

Comment: Try saving a new `Lokal` object and see if the secondary table  gets its data properly inserted.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142399/discussion-between-abdullah-wasi-and-bednarq).

Comment: New Lokal inserted from my Application is properly inserted into db.